# Delete with checkbox won't work

Tags: php, mysqli

For my school i have to make a script, where i can add, edit and delete a record from the database!

Now i'm busy with the delete part, but it won't work.. i try to delete a record by using a checkbox with the ID number of the user.

It keeps saying that the job succeed but it never delete anything... -,-

//delete.php//

```
<?php include "connect.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Verweider gebruiker</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $q="SELECT * FROM naw";
    $result = mysqli_query($server,$q) or die(mysqli_error($server));

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <form action="delete_user.php" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $r[0] ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r[1] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r[2] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r[3] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button>Verweider user(s)</button>
                </td>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
    }

mysqli_close($server);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

//delete_user.php//

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $chk = $_POST['id'];
    $chkcount = count($chk);

    if(!isset($chk))
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('Je moet minimaal 1 bericht selecteren');
        window.location.href = 'delete.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)
        {

        $del = $chk[$i];
        $q="DELETE FROM naw WHERE id=".$del;
    }

        if($q)
        {
            ?>
// this alert i get everytime, but it didn't delete anything... i don't get it :(
        <script>
                alert('De gebruiker is verwijderd');
                window.location.href='gebruiker.php';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Er ging iets fout, probeer het opnieuw');
                window.location.href='delete.php';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try to debug your application 1. look what is going in post request 2. check the query by printing it etc.

Comment: You are defining the delete query but you are not running it..

Comment: @KA_lin OMG how can i be soooo stupid :( THANKS it works now :)

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj Keep up the good work and try to find ways of improving yourself and your code every day :)